# Detect scroll inside Bootstrap Modal & animate each elements on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I was trying to write a code in which when a bootstrap modal is opened a zoomIn animation is fired on scroll to each element.

jsFiddle Link - https://jsfiddle.net/nwxLq2zg/1/

Here is the sample code -

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

         <p>...</p>
         <p>...</p>
         <p>...</p>
         <p>...</p>
         ...   

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function () {

    $(".modal-body").unbind("scroll");

    $(".modal-body").scroll(function(){

        var mScroll = $(this).scrollTop();

        $('.modal-body p').each(function(){

          var eTop = $(this).offset().top;
          console.log('Modal:'+mScroll+'| Element:'+eTop);

          if(eTop >  mScroll) {
            $(this).addClass('animated zoomIn');
          }

        });
    });
});
```

Problem is addClass fired to all elements irrespective of scroll value.I doubt this is because my code couldn't identify individual "< p >" tags. If any one can find answer, it would be really helpful.

Actual Code can be found in this jsFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/nwxLq2zg/1/

Answer (score 0):

I try using `<=` mScroll and adding `-50 on top offset`
Check this fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/nwxLq2zg/5/

```
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function () {

    $(".modal-body").unbind("scroll");

    $(".modal-body").scroll(function(){
        var mScroll = $(this).scrollTop();

        $('.modal-body p').each(function(){
        var eTop = $(this).offset().top - 50;

          if(eTop <=  mScroll) {
            $(this).addClass('animated zoomIn');
          }

        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for ur suggestion, But it still not working  as expected. As you can see when we reach around 70% of scroll all bottom elements have the class added & animation no longer works on last 4-5 items

Comment: @Sree Try using `scrollreveal.js`. Check this fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/nwxLq2zg/8/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Wow.js](http://mynameismatthieu.com/WOW/), it helps revealing information on scroll. All you have to do it download this plugin add the js file in your page and initialize wow on page load.

And in your html you don't need to add classes on run time.

Enjoy :)

Comment: For some reason wow js didn't  work inside Bootstrap modal. It fires animation on all elements even before scroll.